# Blender Internal Rendering half of the image

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

Ok, i am really noob with Blender internal and this never happened to me on Cycles so... help.
The problem is that Blender is only rendering the half of the Image that i want to render:
[image: full image(no render)]

[image: rendered image]

And yes, i have mist enabled, but it doesn't affect enabling/disabling it.

Comment: Hi, could you share your blend file so that I can take a look at it? You can do this by uploading the blend file on this site - blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and copy + pasting the generated url here.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, it looks that when i used Cycles to render the office I used volumetric lights, that means a giant cube covering the render. The solution? deleting the mesh that has the volumetric material.